B&W manga about a guy with a sword who fights monsters that are humans who were infected by a virus
There's this post apocalyptic and futuristic world where humans get infected by some virus and morph into monsters.
The main character fights these monsters in an organization sort of like the one in Kaiju no. 8. He uses a sword and goes out fighting, hoping to die. It's all black and white too.
He gets a partner who's rough but ultimately cares for him and helps him look forward to life a little bit. I believe it's seinen, but I don't remember the name or even character names.
There's also this other character with long black hair who hates the main character because his younger brother unalived himself years ago...
If anything it's sort of similar to No.6 plot wise.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
